# LinkedTo makes y labels disappear

Tags: highcharts

I have two series, and two y axes on both sides of the chart. I would like to use linkedTo, in order to force scaling, but if I add linkedTo: 0 to the first series, the y axis labels disappear (title stays). What is the fix?

I tried:

- giving linkedTo to both axes, if I link first one to 0 and 2nd to 1, labels on both disappear
- playing arround with opposite value, does not affect it
- trying to force them to be enabled with labels: {enabled: true} but didn't work.

  ```
   yAxis: [{
      title: {
          text: 'Primary'
      },
      lineWidth: 1,
      opposite: false,
      tooltip: {
          valueDecimals: 2
      },
  }, {
      title: {
          text: 'Secondary'
      },
      lineWidth: 1,
      opposite: true,
      tooltip: {
          valueDecimals: 0
      },
  }],
  ```

Comment: I replicated your demo and labels don't disappear: http://jsfiddle.net/tLbmLnuc/, please update my code with yours to introduce issue.

Comment: Is it the same code as mine, paste your code and click UPDATE (top nav bar)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tLbmLnuc/1/ here it is. I'm a bit confused about your inclusion of LinkedTo inside a series as opposed to yAxis (like in docs)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tLbmLnuc/3/ The **`linkedTo`** property is to link the two axes. When you use 0 for the first axis, it means you are linking it to itself. I don't know why it doesn't work when you use **`linkedTo: 1`** for the first axis to link to the second axis, but using **`linkedTo: 0`** for the second axis to link to the first one will work.